# configure: error: libarchive not found

Tags: linux, cross-compilation, powerpc

When cross compiling I get:

```
checking whether the /home/ekhnshr/epb2/jenkbuild/toolchain/bin/powerpc-linux-gnu-g++ linker (/home/ekhnshr/epb2/jenkbuild/toolchain/bin/powerpc-linux-gnu-ld) supports shared libraries... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... no
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking for cppcheck... no
configure: WARNING: no cppcheck; cppcheck support disabled
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for archive_read_new in -larchive... no
configure: error: libarchive not found
```

when running: `./configure --host=ppc --build=x86_64 target=ppc --enable-epb2`

settings:

```
export CC=/home/ekhnshr/epb2/jenkbuild/toolchain/bin/powerpc-linux-gnu-gcc
export CXX=/home/ekhnshr/epb2/jenkbuild/toolchain/bin/powerpc-linux-gnu-g++
export CPP=/home/ekhnshr/epb2/jenkbuild/toolchain/bin/powerpc-linux-gnu-cpp
export AS=/home/ekhnshr/epb2/jenkbuild/toolchain/bin/powerpc-linux-gnu-as
```

I am working on x86 Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

If you are compiling for your current platform, you need a development package for [libarchive](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libarchive):

```
sudo apt-get install libarchive-dev
```

However, if you are *cross-compiling*, you may be able to get a suitable package by adding the `-a` option, e.g.,

```
sudo apt-get -a=powerpc install libarchive-dev
```

See also: *[Architecture parameter ignored by apt-get](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133380/architecture-parameter-ignored-by-apt-get)*, which points out that you have to add the given architecture to apt's configuration.

Comment: libarchive-dev is already the newest version

Comment: Yes I was able to use: sudo apt-get -d -o=APT::Architecture="powerpc" install

Comment: But that has lots more dependencies: libmodule-build-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installable
                        Depends: perl (>= 5.13.9) but it is not installable or
                                 libversion-perl (>= 1:0.8700)

Comment: so I did a: sudo apt-get -d -o=APT::Architecture="powerpc" install download libarchive and now I have a .deb, how do I extract that and give a path link?

Comment: [`dpkg-deb`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man1/dpkg-deb.1.html) can extract files (and specify the directory).  There may be a "nice" way to install the package in a nonconflicting tree, but extracting the files is a start.

Comment: Thanks the files are extracted but do you know which variable I need to set now LDFLAGS etc.? so that it points to the libarchive during compilation, it comes during/after the CPP check.

Comment: Usually you would put the `-L`option in `LDFLAGS` to tell the linker what directory the library is in.

Comment: Can it be configured for two paths? I have a toolchain for powerpc libs and the libarchive is extracted on another path.

Comment: You can add multiple `-L` options.

Comment: I added the extracted binary path with the -L option and sourced the variables again but still get the same errors: configure: WARNING: no cppcheck; cppcheck support disabled
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for archive_read_new in -larchive... no
configure: error: libarchive not found

Comment: The `config.log` file would show the attempted command and resulting error messages.

Comment: checking for archive_read_new in -larchive
configure:15590: /home/ekhnshr/toolchain/bin/powerpc-linux-gnu-gcc -std=gnu99 -o conftest -I /home/ekhnshr//toolchain/powerpc-linux-gnu/include -I /home/ekhnshr//toolchain/powerpc-linux-gnu/include -L /home/ekhnshr//toolchain/powerpc-linux-gnu/lib -L /home/ekhnshr//bitboard/libarchdev/usr/lib conftest.c -larchive   >&5
/home/ekhnshr//toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/powerpc-linux-gnu/4.5.2/../../../../powerpc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -larchive
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:15590: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */

Comment: /home/ekhnshr//bitboard/libarchdev/usr/lib contains the extracted .deb